# Node polyfills webpack5 fallback solution not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, polyfills

The node polyfills solution as per webpack5 doc is not working.I tried adding fallback object inside resolve object but the errors are not going away.Please help as to what could be the reason for ignoring the fallbacks by webpack5.